# Scalar Curvature for manifolds expressed as product of sub-manifolds

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, curvature

I am looking for a proof for the fact(please correct me if it is not true) that for a manifold $M=A \times B$ where $A$ and $B$ are also manifolds, the following will hold: $R_M=R_A+R_B$ where $R=R^i_{~i}$, $R^i_{~i}$ being the Ricci tensor. The motivation for the problem is to find the curvature for $AdS_5\times S^5$.

Comment: The proof of this is almost trivial. Have you tried just computing the Ricci scalar of the product space?

Comment: @Prahar I could have just calculated the Ricci scalar for $AdS_5\times S^5$. But I was hunting for a general proof. I tried taking the metric $g_{ij}=A_{ij}+B_{ij}$ where $A_{ij},B_{ij}$ would be block metrics with three blocks as the null matrix. But then I ran into problem while defining the inverses of the $A$ and $B$ tensors. Do you have any other way you suggest?

Comment: You should write $ds^2 = G_{AB} dX^A dX^B = g_{\mu\nu} dx^\mu dx^\nu + h_{ab} dy^a dy^b$ where $g$ and $h$ are two different metrics and $A=(\mu,a)$ is a collective index. We have $G_{\mu\nu} = g_{\mu\nu}$, $G_{\mu a} = 0$ and $G_{ab} = h_{ab}$. The inverse metric is $G^{AB}$ with components $G^{\mu\nu} = g^{\mu\nu}$, $G^{\mu a} = 0$ and $G^{ab} = h^{ab}$. Then you just do the computation.

Comment: I was suggesting a general proof. You don't need to anything more than what I said above to prove the statement. PS - for this and many more general purposes, I find this compendium of formulae very useful - http://people.brandeis.edu/~headrick/HeadrickCompendium.pdf

Comment: I just remembered another thing you will need which is that $g_{\mu\nu}$ depends only on $x$ and $h_{ab}$ depends only on $y$.

Comment: @Prahar Thanks a lot! It was quiet helpful.